why my class cannot convert to ifstream implicitly using std::getline?
I want to convert my class to ifstream implicitly:
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Myclass
{
public:
    operator std::ifstream&(){return ifs_;}
private:
    std::ifstream ifs_;
};

void foo(std::ifstream& ){}

int main()
{
   Myclass a;
   foo(a); //ok
   std::string str;
   std::getline((std::ifstream&)a, str);//ok
   std::getline(a, str);//error
}

function foo works well, but std::getline() has to use an explicit conversion. I don't know why.

Always post complete error along with your question.

Also this is not a [mcve]. Where are all the necessary #includes?. You're also missing ; after class definition.

"but std::getline has to use explicitly conversion..." Because Implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction. See dupe Why does the implicit type conversion not work in template deduction?

Also see std::getline

this is a case where class could extend ifstream instead of containing it
